# too, also or as well?

Tags: word-choice

"Isn't being so smart and talented enough for you, Peter? Do you really have to be so freaking beautiful, too?"

Is the sentence above correct? If it's not, how should I write it? Should I use "also" or "as well" instead of "too"?

Answer (score 0):

"Too" is correct, and probably the best choice. "As well" would also work. "Also" is not usually used this way (at the  end of a sentence).